# Creating new columns in for loop data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to create new columns in for loop.

```
impute.sum <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), -sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
df = data.table(user = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3), x1 = c(NA, 2, 4, NA, NA, 1, 1), x2 = c(1, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA))
df[, x1_1 := impute.sum(x1), by = user]
df[, x2_1 := impute.sum(x2), by = user]
```

I don't know exactly how many columns I will have, so I need to do it with for loop.

Comment: Have you seen the [reference semantics](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignette?

Comment: Thanks, @Arun. I've found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the answer even without using for loop

```
impute.sum <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), -sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
df = data.table(user = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3), x1 = c(NA, 2, 4, NA, NA, 1, 1), x2 = c(1, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA, NA))
in_cols  = c("x1", "x2")
out_cols = c("x1_1", "x2_1")
df[, c(out_cols) := lapply(.SD, impute.sum), by = user, .SDcols = in_cols]
```